# Use grep to remove all occurrences of two values from a list

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a list in a file containing numbers in a range from 1 to 66000. I would like to grep all numbers and exclude numbers 80 and 443. As an example 1080 is ok, as 4431.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @heisen Welcome to SO. Please accept an answer (✓) if something helped or add more details to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -Pv '(^|[^0-9])(80|443)($|[^0-9])' file
```

This prints all lines that don't contain 80 and 443 surrounded by non-numeric characters  or begin/end of line.

```
$ cat file
port 332
port 4443
port 80
port 8080
port 443
332 port
4443 port
80  port
8080 port
443 port
$ grep -Pv '(^|[^0-9])(80|443)($|[^0-9])' file
port 332
port 4443
port 8080
332 port
4443 port
8080 port
```

Comment: I'll just point out that grep's `-P` option isn't ubiquitous, it's a GNU grep feature not found in most unix operating systems. In BSD systems, the `pcre` package provides this functionality with `pcregrep`. Similar functionality can be find in macOS with the `pcre` package from MacPorts or Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
egrep -v '^(80|443)$' yourfile
```

That prints all lines in the file that don't consist of exactly `80` or `443`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Joseph's answer, `egrep` has been deprecated in favor of `grep`, so the answer may better be expressed as:

```bash
grep -Ev '^(80|443)$' yourfile
```

Edit: If there is other information on each line, such as `"80"` or `blah 80 blah` and you want to exclude those lines as well, you can use word boundaries (`\b`) instead of `^` and `$`

```bash
grep -Ev '\b80\b|\b443\b' yourfile
```

Comment: The first example just works for lines that contain port numbers only, the second one wouldn't work for `port80`.

Comment: `grep` has been deprecated in favor of `awk`, so the answer may better be expressed as: `awk '$0!~/^(80|443)$/'` ;-)

Comment: @Cyrus Who would ever deprecate `grep`... Btw, you can rewrite that to `awk '!/^(80|443)$/'`.

Comment: The `egrep` command has only been deprecated in the GNU environment. There's a much larger world of unix systems out there for whom `egrep` is and will remain a standard part of the toolset, along with `fgrep`. There's no indication as to what operating system the OP is running. Don't presume it's the same as yours.

Comment: @ghoti Assuming we know nothing about the OS OP is running, would `grep` not be the most universally accepted option?

Comment: @user3764734, yes, it would. And if "the most universally accepted option" is a goal, asserting limitations based on just one operating system should be avoided, especially if you express those limitations such that they might be mistaken as being universal. `egrep` is a perfectly acceptable solution outside of your backyard.